# Match background color with random color div on scroll-snap using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm practicing by making this website - https://backstagetalks.com/
I created divs that are scrollable and made it such that each generates a random color.

However I want to know how to use Javascript to identify when a particular div has snapped to the center so that it can set the background color to match the color of that div

I tried to use the scrollX, scrollY and offSetTop, offsetHeight properties.
But the divs all have fixed offsetHeight, so it didn't work

I don't know jquery yet and I haven't started learning CSS or JS libraries/frameworks, so I don't know how to use those to help.

This is the Code:

```js
const gra = function (min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const init = function () {
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(".scroller div");
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        items[i].style.minHeight = gra(100, 100) + "vh";

        const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        items[i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
        let itemColor = items[i].style.backgroundColor;
        // items[i].style.borderColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
    }
}
init();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&family=Chivo+Mono:ital,wght@1,500&family=Hanalei+Fill&family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    /* font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

header {
    padding: 0.7em 0 0 0 ;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Bangers';
    font-size: 25px;
}

header h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* border: 2px solid brown; */
}

.scroller {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    z-index: 1;
 
}

.book {
    /* border: 20px solid; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* padding: 1em; */
    width: 300px;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    scroll-padding-top: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
}


.links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.links h2 {
    font-family: 'Fredoka One';
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 0;
}

.issue-list {
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.issue-list p{
    margin: 0;
}

.issue-list p a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.info p {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Chivo Mono';
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="container">
    <header>
        <h2>BACKSTAGE TALKS</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="info">
        <p> Backstage Talks is a magazine <br>
            casual, but in depth dialogues <br>
            on design and business. Our decisions <br>
            shape and influence this complex <br>
            world—to have a chance to make the <br>
            right ones, we need to talk </p>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll-box" class="scroller">
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-1">1</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-2">2</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-3">3</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-4">4</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-5">5</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-6">6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
        <h2>info@backstagetalks.com</h2>
        <div class="issue-list">
            <p id="issue1"><a href="#book_issue-1">Issue #1</a></p>
            <p id="issue2"><a href="#book_issue-2">Issue #2</a></p>
            <p id="issue3"><a href="#book_issue-3">Issue #3</a></p>
            <p id="issue4"><a href="#book_issue-4">Issue #4</a></p>
            <p id="issue5"><a href="#book_issue-5">Issue #5</a></p>
            <p id="issue6"><a href="#book_issue-6">Issue #6</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: The value from `randomColor` can be invalid (0 - FF and 10000 - FFFFF), you can fix this by filling them up with leading zeroes. For example: `('00000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16)).substr(-6)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check when one of your books `div` has snapped using a javascript function (`scrollHandler` in this example) like the one from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66029649/5334486

Once you know when the "snapped" event happens, you can loop over your books divs and check which one of them is currently displayed testing whether `getBoundingClientRect().top` equals zero.

Finally, once you know which div is currently snapped, you can assign the same background color to `body`.

```js
const gra = function(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const init = function() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll(".scroller div");
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    items[i].style.minHeight = gra(100, 100) + "vh";

    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    items[i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
    let itemColor = items[i].style.backgroundColor;
    // items[i].style.borderColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
  }
}
init();


function scrollHandler(e) {
  var atSnappingPoint = e.target.scrollTop % e.target.offsetHeight === 0;
  var timeOut = atSnappingPoint ? 0 : 150;

  clearTimeout(e.target.scrollTimeout);

  e.target.scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    //using the timeOut to evaluate scrolling state
    if (!timeOut) {
      console.log('Scroller snapped!');
      document.querySelectorAll(".scroller div").forEach(theDiv => {
         if (theDiv.id, theDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top == 0) {
             // THIS IS THE CURRENTLY SNAPPED BOOK
             console.log(theDiv.id, theDiv.style.backgroundColor)
             document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = theDiv.style.backgroundColor
         }
      });
    }
  }, timeOut);
}



document.querySelector(".scroller").addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&family=Chivo+Mono:ital,wght@1,500&family=Hanalei+Fill&family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

header {
  padding: 0.7em 0 0 0;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Bangers';
  font-size: 25px;
}

header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* border: 2px solid brown; */
}

.scroller {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  z-index: 1;
}

.book {
  /* border: 20px solid; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* padding: 1em; */
  width: 300px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-padding-top: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.links h2 {
  font-family: 'Fredoka One';
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 0;
}

.issue-list {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.issue-list p {
  margin: 0;
}

.issue-list p a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.info p {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Chivo Mono';
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="container">
  <header>
    <h2>BACKSTAGE TALKS</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="info">
    <p> Backstage Talks is a magazine <br> casual, but in depth dialogues <br> on design and business. Our decisions <br> shape and influence this complex <br> world—to have a chance to make the <br> right ones, we need to talk </p>
  </div>
  <div id="scroll-box" class="scroller">
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-1">1</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-2">2</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-3">3</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-4">4</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-5">5</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-6">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <h2>info@backstagetalks.com</h2>
    <div class="issue-list">
      <p id="issue1"><a href="#book_issue-1">Issue #1</a></p>
      <p id="issue2"><a href="#book_issue-2">Issue #2</a></p>
      <p id="issue3"><a href="#book_issue-3">Issue #3</a></p>
      <p id="issue4"><a href="#book_issue-4">Issue #4</a></p>
      <p id="issue5"><a href="#book_issue-5">Issue #5</a></p>
      <p id="issue6"><a href="#book_issue-6">Issue #6</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. This one worked just as perfect. 

I actually saw that solution in the link you referenced. But I'm curious as to why use 150 in the conditional statement?

Comment: @TeDi it basically waits 150 milliseconds before evaluating the scrolling status, UNLESS the div is finished snapping (`e.target.scrollTop % e.target.offsetHeight === 0` means it is at the top of the viewport) in which case it doesn't wait and actually fires the routine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check through the scroll positions of the divs individually and attach a srcoll event listener on the `.scroll-box`, then assign the colors based on the scroll position.

```js
const gra = function (min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const init = function () {
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(".scroller div");
    let positions = [];
    let itemcolors = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        let item = items[i];
        
        item.style.minHeight = gra(100, 100) + "vh";
        const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        item.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
        let itemColor = item.style.backgroundColor;
        
        // Arrays to hold colors and position in same index positions
        itemcolors.push(itemColor)
        positions.push(item.offsetTop)
        /* on scrolling, get the offset and check against the existing
        scroll positions of the divs */
        
        document.getElementById('scroll-box').addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            let scrolloffset = document.getElementById('scroll-box').scrollTop
            positions.forEach((position, index) => {
                // Give an allowance of + or - 5 for padding and other spacing factors
                if(position >= (scrolloffset-5) && position <= (scrolloffset+5)){
                    document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundColor = itemcolors[index];
                }
            })
        })
        
        // items[i].style.borderColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
    }
    
}
init();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&family=Chivo+Mono:ital,wght@1,500&family=Hanalei+Fill&family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    /* font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

header {
    padding: 0.7em 0 0 0 ;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Bangers';
    font-size: 25px;
}

header h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* border: 2px solid brown; */
}

.scroller {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    z-index: 1;
 
}

.book {
    /* border: 20px solid; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* padding: 1em; */
    width: 300px;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    scroll-padding-top: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
}


.links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.links h2 {
    font-family: 'Fredoka One';
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 0;
}

.issue-list {
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.issue-list p{
    margin: 0;
}

.issue-list p a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.info p {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Chivo Mono';
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="container">
    <header>
        <h2>BACKSTAGE TALKS</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="info">
        <p> Backstage Talks is a magazine <br>
            casual, but in depth dialogues <br>
            on design and business. Our decisions <br>
            shape and influence this complex <br>
            world—to have a chance to make the <br>
            right ones, we need to talk </p>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll-box" class="scroller">
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-1">1</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-2">2</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-3">3</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-4">4</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-5">5</div>
        <div class="book" id="book_issue-6">6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
        <h2>info@backstagetalks.com</h2>
        <div class="issue-list">
            <p id="issue1"><a href="#book_issue-1">Issue #1</a></p>
            <p id="issue2"><a href="#book_issue-2">Issue #2</a></p>
            <p id="issue3"><a href="#book_issue-3">Issue #3</a></p>
            <p id="issue4"><a href="#book_issue-4">Issue #4</a></p>
            <p id="issue5"><a href="#book_issue-5">Issue #5</a></p>
            <p id="issue6"><a href="#book_issue-6">Issue #6</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked when I tried this. 
But since this is the first time it's working as expected, I noticed that it loads to random divs instead of the first one. 

I tried use the scrollIntoView() function to get it to load the first div by default. It worked.
But I still see that scrolling effect, which I don't want. Any ideas?

Comment: If you've been able to fix the random divs issue.. Then to remove the scrolling effect you'll have to access the `scroll-behavior` of the **.scroller** class, since that's what is making it smooth scroll. You'll have to do this with javascript by setting it to `auto` a few moments before the page loads thereafter set it to `smooth`,

Comment: Okay I did that. But it's still not giving me exactly what I wanted. Is it possible to make it always load the first div by default ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you well, by first div do you mean load the div with `id=book-issue-1` or do you mean the background should always have the color of the first div's background? If it's the latter, then I think it's already working that way since it always shows the **number 1** everytime it loads, so i don't really get your question. Please elaborate more

Comment: Oh Okay. I meant the former. I want the first div to load by default without using scrollIntoView() function to always take it back there.
Basically, I want to get rid of the random divs loading at page refresh, but I'm having trouble doing it. I don't know if it's a problem with the JS or CSS, because I've worked on a previous scroll-snap project and didn't have this issue.

Comment: I think I've understood you now, the reason it's loading different divs for you on page refresh is because you're probably reloading the page when it has a value like `#book_issue-3` appended to the **URL** (After clicking one of those Issue links). So the page automatically scrolls to the div with that id, hence the scrolling effect to the div. But generally on a normal case without a **href** appended to the url it should load from the top by default. Remove that href from the url and see what happens. Meanwhile, I can implement a silent scroll feature since the issue is now clear

Answer (score 0):

You can test if an element is (completly) inside the viewport by using [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) and compare the values to the window w/h.

```js
const gra = function(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const init = function() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll(".scroller div");
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    items[i].style.minHeight = gra(100, 100) + "vh";

    const randomColor = ('00000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16)).substr(-6);
    items[i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
    let itemColor = items[i].style.backgroundColor;
    // items[i].style.borderColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
  }
}
init();

function isInViewport(element) {
  const { top, left, bottom, right } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    top >= 0 &&
    left >= 0 &&
    bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}
const scroller = document.querySelector(".scroller");

scroller.addEventListener("scroll", ({ target }) => {
  [...target.childNodes]
    .filter(child => child.nodeType != 3 && isInViewport(child))
    .forEach(child => background.style.backgroundColor = child.style.backgroundColor);
});
/* initial */
scroller.dispatchEvent(new Event("scroll"));
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&family=Chivo+Mono:ital,wght@1,500&family=Hanalei+Fill&family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

header {
  padding: 0.7em 0 0 0;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Bangers';
  font-size: 25px;
}

header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* border: 2px solid brown; */
}

.scroller {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  z-index: 1;
}

.book {
  /* border: 20px solid; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* padding: 1em; */
  width: 300px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-padding-top: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.links h2 {
  font-family: 'Fredoka One';
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 0;
}

.issue-list {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.issue-list p {
  margin: 0;
}

.issue-list p a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.info p {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Chivo Mono';
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="container">
  <header>
    <h2>BACKSTAGE TALKS</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="info">
    <p> Backstage Talks is a magazine <br> casual, but in depth dialogues <br> on design and business. Our decisions <br> shape and influence this complex <br> world—to have a chance to make the <br> right ones, we need to talk </p>
  </div>
  <div id="scroll-box" class="scroller">
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-1">1</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-2">2</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-3">3</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-4">4</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-5">5</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-6">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <h2>info@backstagetalks.com</h2>
    <div class="issue-list">
      <p id="issue1"><a href="#book_issue-1">Issue #1</a></p>
      <p id="issue2"><a href="#book_issue-2">Issue #2</a></p>
      <p id="issue3"><a href="#book_issue-3">Issue #3</a></p>
      <p id="issue4"><a href="#book_issue-4">Issue #4</a></p>
      <p id="issue5"><a href="#book_issue-5">Issue #5</a></p>
      <p id="issue6"><a href="#book_issue-6">Issue #6</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

There is also a more modern way with the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

```js
const gra = function(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const init = function() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll(".scroller div");
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    items[i].style.minHeight = gra(100, 100) + "vh";

    const randomColor = ('00000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16)).substr(-6);
    items[i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
    let itemColor = items[i].style.backgroundColor;
    // items[i].style.borderColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
  }
}
init();

const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: [0.51] // 51% visible
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((list) => {
  list.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.51) {
        background.style.backgroundColor = entry.target.style.backgroundColor;
      }
  })
}, options);
/* observe every child except text nodes */
document.querySelector(".scroller").childNodes.forEach(child => child.nodeType != 3 && observer.observe(child));
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&family=Chivo+Mono:ital,wght@1,500&family=Hanalei+Fill&family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

header {
  padding: 0.7em 0 0 0;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Bangers';
  font-size: 25px;
}

header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* border: 2px solid brown; */
}

.scroller {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  z-index: 1;
}

.book {
  /* border: 20px solid; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* padding: 1em; */
  width: 300px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-padding-top: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.links h2 {
  font-family: 'Fredoka One';
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 0;
}

.issue-list {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.issue-list p {
  margin: 0;
}

.issue-list p a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* padding: 0 1em; */
}

.info p {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Chivo Mono';
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="container">
  <header>
    <h2>BACKSTAGE TALKS</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="info">
    <p> Backstage Talks is a magazine <br> casual, but in depth dialogues <br> on design and business. Our decisions <br> shape and influence this complex <br> world—to have a chance to make the <br> right ones, we need to talk </p>
  </div>
  <div id="scroll-box" class="scroller">
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-1">1</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-2">2</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-3">3</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-4">4</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-5">5</div>
    <div class="book" id="book_issue-6">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <h2>info@backstagetalks.com</h2>
    <div class="issue-list">
      <p id="issue1"><a href="#book_issue-1">Issue #1</a></p>
      <p id="issue2"><a href="#book_issue-2">Issue #2</a></p>
      <p id="issue3"><a href="#book_issue-3">Issue #3</a></p>
      <p id="issue4"><a href="#book_issue-4">Issue #4</a></p>
      <p id="issue5"><a href="#book_issue-5">Issue #5</a></p>
      <p id="issue6"><a href="#book_issue-6">Issue #6</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```